# Differences between `Job` of k8s to the `units` of systemd?

Tags: kubernetes, jobs, systemd

Considering `Kubernetes 1.13`, how does compare the features of the `Job` object to the features available around the `units` of `systemd`? And vice-versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not meaningfully compare. The closest you could say is that a Job object is vaguely similar to a `oneshot`-mode service unit in systemd, in that both run a process until completion and that's it. But a service unit can't run multiple copies and systemd's containment features are different from K8s/Docker.